# Computer crashes when shutting down

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Sometimes, when I shut down my computer, it does not shut down, but it restarts. When I log in, I get the message that Windows recovered from an unexpected shutdown:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   9f
  BCP1: 0000000000000003
  BCP2: FFFFFA8007057BB0
  BCP3: FFFFF80000B9C3D8
  BCP4: FFFFFA80074137C0
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\070314-27565-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-202754-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

You can find the dump file in the code block at the bottom. I've also tried the "Check for solution" button, but that dialog box just disappears after some time and does not show a solution.

What is causing this issue? And how can I fix this?

```
    Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


    Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\070314-27565-01.dmp]
    Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?00000000`00000000?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?fffff8a0`002b76c2?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?fffff8a0`08437c32?
    DbsSplayTreeRangeMap::Add: ignoring zero-sized range at ?fffff800`00b9c3c0?
    Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
    Executable search path is: 
    Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
    Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
    Built by: 7601.18409.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144
    Machine Name:
    Kernel base = 0xfffff800`03058000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`0329b890
    Debug session time: Thu Jul  3 20:22:22.486 2014 (UTC + 2:00)
    System Uptime: 0 days 12:05:52.703
    Loading Kernel Symbols
    ...............................................................
    ................................................................
    ..............................................................
    Loading User Symbols
    Loading unloaded module list
    ........
    *******************************************************************************
    *                                                                             *
    *                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
    *                                                                             *
    *******************************************************************************

    Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

    BugCheck 9F, {3, fffffa8007057bb0, fffff80000b9c3d8, fffffa80074137c0}

    Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxNetAdp.sys, Win32 error 0n2
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for VBoxNetAdp.sys
    *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for VBoxNetAdp.sys
    Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp

    Followup: MachineOwner
    ---------
```

If I run the `!analyze -v`, I get:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver is causing an inconsistent power state.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: fffffa8007057bb0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff80000b9c3d8, Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: fffffa80074137c0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MODULE_NAME: ntkrnlmp

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff88000db9000 VBoxNetAdp

IRP_ADDRESS:  fffffa80074137c0

DEVICE_OBJECT: fffffa800a397050

DRIVER_OBJECT: fffffa800a37e220

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00b9c388 fffff800`0313d8d2 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 fffffa80`07057bb0 fffff800`00b9c3d8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00b9c390 fffff800`030d885c : fffff800`00b9c4c0 fffff800`00b9c4c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x33af0
fffff800`00b9c430 fffff800`030d86f6 : fffffa80`0a93c758 fffffa80`0a93c758 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable+0x6c
fffff800`00b9c4a0 fffff800`030d85de : 00000065`676f3757 fffff800`00b9cb18 00000000`002a998e fffff800`0324c448 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0xc6
fffff800`00b9caf0 fffff800`030d83c7 : 00000018`b371f8c5 00000018`002a998e 00000018`b371f83d 00000000`0000008e : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`00b9cb90 fffff800`030c58ca : fffff800`03248e80 fffff800`03256cc0 00000000`00000001 fffff880`00000000 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`00b9cc40 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`00b9d000 fffff800`00b97000 fffff800`00b9cc00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_IMAGE_ntkrnlmp

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_IMAGE_ntkrnlmp

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: "*the dmp file shows ASCII characters*" - how do you open it?

Comment: @gronostaj I open it with Notepad.

Comment: Well, it's not a text file, but a binary dumpfile. Notepad is a text editor, so don't expect to see anything but text when opening files in Notepad ([related question](http://superuser.com/a/693525/194694)). Use a dedicated BSOD dump viewer or send us the file.

Comment: @gronostaj Done, I've opened it with WinDbg and included it in my question.

Comment: fix the symbol path: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503

Comment: @magicandre1981 Done, I've added the new dump result.

Comment: VBoxNetAdp sounds like a VirtualBox issue. Do you use the latest version?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, when I try to update it says that I use the latest version.

Comment: report this in their bugtracker/forum

Comment: It seems that it's already reported: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the problem disappeared without I have really done something.

The problem that I had here has been reported as a VirtualBox bug: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11730
It is currently not yet fixed. I've posted my dump output there, it could be helpful.